# Is there a way to use get_int function in VS code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50

**EDIT** My problem is solved Thanks all very much
the problem was that I only included cs50.h but didn't include cs50.c and that the library I had was an old one containing only GetInt but not get_int
when I downloaded the new library everything worked

I'm taking CS50x course and I want to use `get_int` function which is included in cs50 library on VS code ...
I downloaded cs50 library and copied cs50.h and cs50.c to d:\MinGW\bin

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)
{
    int age = get_int("Age?");
    int days=age*365;
    printf("Your age is %i which means that you are %i days old", age, days);
}
```

when I try to compile it using

```
gcc 0.c -o 0
```

it writes

```
0.c: In function 'main':
0.c:7:15: warning: implicit declaration of 
function 'get_int' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    7 |     int age = get_int("Age?");     
      |               ^~~~~~~
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\AbdoMAD\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTefKbe.o:0.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `get_int'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the auto complete of vs code doesn't have `get_int` but it has `GetInt`
But when I use it and the code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("Age?")
    int age = GetInt();
    int days=age*365;
    printf("Your age is %i which means that you are %i days old", age, days);
}
```

it returns

```
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\AbdoMAD\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3NVsiz.o:1.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `GetInt'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do to use get_int or at least GetInt in VS code??

Comment: You have to link against the library, CS50 provides

Comment: @JCWasmx86  Excuse me but how do that?   if by typing -lcs50 when compiling it doesn't work either

Comment: You could take the cs50 source code, copy it and compile with your file.

Comment: The warning indicates a missing function declaration. That's not a linker problem. Does the header `cs50.h` provide a declaration of `get_int()`?

Comment: Does the compiler find the header at all?

Comment: @KamilCuk if you mean to copy cs50.c    I tried but gives the same problem

Comment: @Gerhardh the problem with get_int is bcz the library I've downloaded define GetInt instead of get_int             but there is a problem with GetInt too which says undefined reference to GetInt

Comment: @Gerhardh it ought to find the header , it suggests the function and says it is from cs50.h file

Comment: Maybe related: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/29977/implicit-declaration-of-function-get-int-is-invalid-in-c99?

Comment: @Bob__ what is update50 mentioned there??

Comment: About update50 : https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/33088/update50-command-not-found-in-cs50-ide

Comment: @AbdoMAD, If want to notify that the problem is solved, the proper way is to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want [get_int](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h#L82), don't write it `GetInt`.

If you use https://sandbox.cs50.io, you can do:

```
gcc 0.c -lcs50 -o 0
```

and you first code will work.

To get more information, try googling "c link to library".

Comment: I use it in cs50 sandbox but i want to use it in VS code

Comment: You can try to put `cs50.c` in the same folder as `0.c` and execute `gcc 0.c cs50.c -o 0`. A more clean way is to first compile `cs50.c` to an object `cs50.o` and use that object in the compilation of `0.c`.

Comment: i did so and it worked for GetInt      what does this mean ? i mean what is wrong with me linking the lib or whatever is called?         also, is there a way to not put cs50.c in every folder I want to work in?((edit* i included cs50.c and removed it from the folder and it worked too , thanks))     and lastly if you can help me use get_int in vscode that would be great

Comment: Don't do `#include "cs50.c"` (you said "i included cs50.c"). It can give you bad surprises afterwards if you don't understand correctly what you are doing.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand . So is there an alternative for having to put in in the same folder and then compiling using it ??

Comment: Instead of `gcc 0.c cs50.c -o 0`, you can execute `gcc 0.c /<path_to_cs50.c>/cs50.c -o 0`. If you want to do it in a better way, you should look for `Makefile`.